# How to know if iOS user declined permission or not on react-native?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have an app that requires camera access. On android side I am asking for permission but on iOS
side you don't have to request permission because Apple do it for you (from plist). But in that case I don't know if iOS user accepted or rejected the permission request. How can I know user is accepted request or not on iOS device.

If user will decline the permission I will navigate to other screen and if accepted camera will open.

I didn't find any answer on stackoverflow or react-native documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the implementation here https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-permissions

Comment: For expo take a look at https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/permissions.html

Answer (score 1):

An unified permissions API for React Native on iOS and Android.

[https://github.com/yonahforst/react-native-permissions](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-permissions)

Answer (score 1):

You could use permissions library to ask for permission, and store whether you already asked it in the device local AsyncStorage.

I am not sure it is possible to tell whether they've rejected some permissions from the OS.